# How to check is an user has a role on discord

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am struggling to find a way to check if an user has a role.
I know how to find a certain role:

```
public Role findRole(Guild guild, String name) {
    List<Role> roles = guild.getRolesByName(name, true);

    if (roles.size() <= 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Role with name " + name + " on Guild " + guild.getName() + " not found!");
    } else {
        return roles.get(0);
    }
}
```

and i have a role: `Role neededEole=findRole(event.getGuild(),"Admin");`

I know how to search an user: `String user=event.getAuthor().getId();`
or: `User user=event.getAuthor();`

But i don't know how to get those two work together in JDA to check if that user has that role.

Can please someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Member` object puts a user in the guild context. You can get the member with `Guild#getMember(user)`. This gives you the option to retrieve guild information of this user:

```java
Member member = guild.getMember(user);
Member member = guild.getMemberById(userId);
List<Member> member = guild.getMembersByName(name, true);
List<Member> member = guild.getMembersByRoles(role);
```

```java
public Role findRole(Member member, String name) {
    List<Role> roles = member.getRoles();
    return roles.stream()
                .filter(role -> role.getName().equals(name)) // filter by role name
                .findFirst() // take first result
                .orElse(null); // else return null
}
```

Other ways to access a member instance are outlined in the `See Also` section of the member documentation: [Member](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Member.html). Some events also offer a `getMember()` alternative if the event could happen in a guild context.

Comment: Than you very much, days of searching this, you helped me a lot, it works, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is 1+ year old but for the people coming here to check this you can just do this (I did static in this code because I was putting it in another class):

```
public static boolean hasRole(Member member, Role role) {
  List<Role> memberRoles = member.getRoles();
  return memberRoles.contains(role);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since there's no such feature in the doc yet, you can do this:

```
boolean hasRole;
  for(int i=0; i<builder.getGuildById(guild).getMemberById(userId).getRoles().size(); i++){
    if("RoleName".equals(builder.getGuildById(guild).getMemberById(userId).getRoles().get(i).getName())){
      hasRole = true;
    }
  }
```

Then, for true `if (hasRole)` or false `if (!hasRole)`