# How to check if the sender of the message has specific roles JDA

Tags: java, discord

I want to know how to see if the sender has a specific role use the

```
    public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String message = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().toString().toLowerCase(); 
        String[] messageArr = message.split(" ");
        if (event.getAuthor().isBot())return;
```

So how using the event variable I can check if the sender has a specific role using event.
something like

```
event.getAuthor()
```

to see if the user has role

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check is an user has a role on discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924386/how-to-check-is-an-user-has-a-role-on-discord)

Comment: Ye ok i found how
```    public Role findRole(Member member, String roleName) {
        java.util.List<Role> roles = member.getRoles();
        return roles.stream()
                    .filter(role -> role.getName().equals(roleName)) // filter by role name
                    .findFirst() // take first result
                    .orElse(null); // else return null
    }
```
then 
```
      Role e = findRole(event.getMember(), "name");
      if (e.equals(null)) return;
```